# Type and function for dividing into Tuple of variable length

Tags: typescript

**Problem**
I want to create a function, alongside a typing for said function, that allows me to divide an array into a tuple containing a variable number of typed arrays. The idea is   call .divide on an array instance, and provide a variable number of typeguards/typeguard like functions, the output of divide would be a Tuple containing the same number of typed arrays as typeguards provided. If items do not fit any provided typeguard, they are discarded from the result. Sample usage:

```
const [typeAs, typeBs, typeCs] = myArr.divide(isTypeA, isTypeB, isTypeC);
const [typeFs] = myArr.divide(isTypeF)
const [typeAs, typeFs, typeDs, typeCs, typeXYZs] = myArr.divide(isTypeA,isTypeF,isTypeD,isTypeC,isTypeXYZ)
//etc
```

As a starting point I've attempted to create a function that divides to 3 vs. a variable length Tuple + args list. I've thrown together the following on an interface for Array:

```
type TGuard<S> = ((input: any) => input is S) | ((input: any) => boolean);
divide<OrigType, NewT1, NewT2, NewT3>(
            t1: TGuard<NewT1>,
            t2: TGuard<NewT2>,
            t3: TGuard<NewT3>,
        ): [NewT1[], NewT2[], NewT3[]];
```

and an implementation:

```
Array.prototype.divide = function <OGType, NewT1, NewT2, NewT3>(
    t1: TGuard<NewT1>,
    t2: TGuard<NewT2>,
    t3: TGuard<NewT3>,
): [NewT1[], NewT2[], NewT3[]] {
    const d3: [NewT1[], NewT2[], NewT3[]] = [[], [], []];
    const discards: OGType[] = [];
    this.forEach((item) => {
        t1(item) ? d3[0].push(item) : t2(item) ? d3[1].push(item) : t3(item) ? d3[2].push(item) : discards.push(item);
    });

    return d3;
};
```

This works but I'm at a loss on expanding this to accept a variable number of typeguards, and produce a variable number of typed arrays in a Tuple wrapper. I have several ideas for the eventual implementation, At present the main challenge I'm facing is the type signature

Comment: Maybe like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wRzQLw) with a mapped type in the return type (includes implementation that works for any number of guards as well)?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75032228/type-and-function-for-dividing-into-tuple-of-variable-length#comment132409387_75032228) @vera. I interpret the question as wanting essentially that implementation, but with the mapped return type as arrays `... => item is infer U ? U[] : unknown[]`

Comment: @jbailie1991 I think there might be some confusion regarding terminology. In TS, a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) type "is another sort of `Array` type that knows exactly how many elements it contains, and exactly which types it contains at specific positions." There is no such thing as a "tuple of variable length".

Comment: @jsejcksn ‍♀️ Of course, how could I have missed that... It's too late to edit the comment, so here's the [corrected playground](https://tsplay.dev/WokZjW).

Comment: I guess I'm too late to the party of writing this code, but I'd just like to remind people that [it is widely considered bad practice to modify native prototypes this way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14034180/2887218).

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75032228/type-and-function-for-dividing-into-tuple-of-variable-length?noredirect=1#comment132411241_75032228) https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJl5E.jpg

Answer (score 0):

If we define `divide` like this:

```
function divide<T, G extends (((item: T) => item is any) | ((item: T) => boolean))[]>(array: T[], ...guards: G): InferGuards<G>;
```

then we can map over `G` and infer the guard types:

```
type InferGuards<G> = {
    [K in keyof G]: G[K] extends (item: any) => item is infer U ? U[] : unknown[];
};
```

If the element isn't a type guard, then the resulting type should be `unknown[]`, since we don't really know what the type should be.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WokZjW)